# mktime or tz database unexpected return for 1941

Tags: c, mktime, ubuntu-20.04, tzdata

mktime returns for july 3rd 1941 (00:00:00) and july 4th 1941 (00:00:00) are unexpected.
The difference between the two is 82800 seconds, lacking a full hour (3600).

The C program diff1941.c (see below) shows the following :

```
    $> diff1941

    july3=-899337600i
    diff:82800 should be 86400
```

At first I thought it was a TZ Database hour shift, but as far as I understand, and according to zdump command, there is no such shift for 1941.

```
    zdump -v -c 1940,1943 /etc/localtime

    /etc/localtime  Sun Feb 25 01:59:59 1940 UT = Sun Feb 25 01:59:59 1940 WET isdst=0 gmtoff=0
    /etc/localtime  Sun Feb 25 02:00:00 1940 UT = Sun Feb 25 03:00:00 1940 WEST isdst=1 gmtoff=3600
    /etc/localtime  Fri Jun 14 21:59:59 1940 UT = Fri Jun 14 22:59:59 1940 WEST isdst=1 gmtoff=3600
    /etc/localtime  Fri Jun 14 22:00:00 1940 UT = Sat Jun 15 00:00:00 1940 CEST isdst=1 gmtoff=7200
    /etc/localtime  Mon Nov  2 00:59:59 1942 UT = Mon Nov  2 02:59:59 1942 CEST isdst=1 gmtoff=7200
    /etc/localtime  Mon Nov  2 01:00:00 1942 UT = Mon Nov  2 02:00:00 1942 CET isdst=0 gmtoff=3600
```

So at this point I am confused. Either my program has a bug that I can not see (possible), or there is a bug in lib C mktime function(unlikely), or there is something subtle in the TZ database and I can not find it (probable): what do you think of it ?

I am using:

- Ubuntu 20.04 64 bits,
- libc 2.31-0ubuntu9,
- tzdata 2019c-3ubuntu1
- /etc/localtime points on /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris

diff1941.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

long int stamp(int d,int m,int y)
{
   struct tm date;
   memset(&date,0,sizeof(date));

   date.tm_mday=d;
   date.tm_mon=m-1;
   date.tm_year=y-1900;

   return mktime(&date);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc>1)
        setenv("TZ","0",1);
    long int july3=stamp(3,7,1941);
    long int july4=stamp(4,7,1941);

    printf("july3=%ldi\n",july3);
    printf("diff:%ld should be 86400\n",july4-july3);
}
```

Comment: Isn't a date with `isdst=0` invalid in France for that period? With `isdst=-1` and `isdst=1` it works fine.

Comment: I ran your program here and it printed: `july3=-899319600i diff:86400 should be 86400`. I am using `America/New_York` for TZ file. You may want to try for other timezones. You may need to either relink `/etc/localtime` or add a shared library that intercepts the open and redirects (e.g. `LD_LIBRARY_PRELOAD`)

Comment: KamilCuk, you are apparently right. Though I just tried on a Ubuntu 18.04 host, and it's fine either way (with idst=0, -1 or 1). I still don't understand why 3rd and 4th of july are treated differently with isdst forced to 0. If nobody else has a better answer I will accept yours. thank you.

Comment: Well, I can reproduce your behavior in both `Europe/France` and my `Europe/Warsaw`. Well, I believe the answer to 'why' will come from understanding the glibc mktime function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, when you see 1 hour difference in time, that means you should take a look at daylight saving time settings.

On both dates 3rd July 1941 and 4th July 1941 daylight saving time was in effect in France. You specify `tm_isdst = 0`, that means the daylight saving time is not in effect for your dates. So your dates are invalid - there was no such time as 3rd July 1941 with 00:00:00 with no DST.

Glibc `mktime` [tries it's best](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/time/mktime.c#L503) to determine what time do you have in mind. Actually it determines the first of the dates as 3rd July 1941 02:00:00 and the second of the dates as 4th July 1941 01:00:00. The difference is one day minus one hour.

Either set `isdst=-1` to let `mktime` "automagically" determine the current DST for your input times. In France it was DST all the time in 1941, it will determine `isdst=1`. Or explicit specify that you want DST by setting `date.isdst=1`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and especially the link to glibc mktime source code.